# Join 3 tables incorrect results

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables with common key `organization_id`.

Based on transaction number I'm able to find specific transaction from table 1 with value for example `reason_code=B5`, so..

In table #1, `transaction`, there's a column `reason_code = 'B5'`.

In table #2, `reason_code`, there's a column `reason_code = 'B5' and description = 'XYZ'`

In table #3, `translation` there's a column `translation_key = 'XYZ'` (same value as for column `description` in table #2) and column `Translation`.

I'm interested in the value from column `TRANSLATION` in table #3 which is related through table #2 with table #1.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    description, c.trans_seq 
FROM 
    Translation a
INNER JOIN
    com_reason_code b ON a.organization_id = b.organization_id
INNER JOIN 
    transaction c ON a.organization_id = c.organization_id
WHERE 
    c.trans_seq = '500'
```

I'm getting over 1000 results where `c.trans_seq = 500` but if I run this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM transaction 
WHERE trans_seq = '500'
```

I only get one row. To be honest I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check your join - you seem to join all three tables on organization_id, but by your description it sounds like you join transaction to reason_code on reason_code.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

without actually seeing the table structures and data, i'm filling in the blanks as best as i can based on your description and with only 1 record per table since i do not know your variations in the tables' data.

```
create table transactions (organization_id int, reason_code nvarchar(2), trans_seq int)
create table reasoncode (organization_id int, reason_code nvarchar(20), descriptions nvarchar(100))
create table translations (organization_id int, translation nvarchar(100), translation_key nvarchar(100))

insert transactions
select 1, 'B5', 500

insert reasoncode
select 1, 'B5', 'Big Bad Boy 5'

insert translations
select 1, 'Little Red 2', 'Big Bad Boy 5'


select a.trans_seq, c.translation
from transactions a
        inner join reasoncode b on a.organization_id = b.organization_id and a.reason_code = b.reason_code
            inner join translations c on b.organization_id = c.organization_id and b.descriptions = c.translation_key
where a.trans_seq = 500

drop table transactions
drop table reasoncode
drop table translations
```

this will get you your result however you may/will need to modify based on your tables' struncture and data.

Comment: cool, glad it worked out for you! please mark it as the answer.